# How does ${!#} work in bash to get the last command-line argument?

Tags: bash

From the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, to get the last command-line argument:

> Or: `lastarg=${!#}`
>    This is an
>   *indirect reference* to the `$#` variable.
>    Note that `lastarg=${!$#}` doesn't work.

Comment: As an aside, the ABS is quite frowned on as a reference; see http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs for the history of its factoid in the irc.freenode.org#bash channel. The [Bash-Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are not as infamous for density of inaccuracies. Within the latter, indirect references are covered in detail in [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006); in the former, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection

Comment: Just a question: Isn't `!$` simpler and the same?

Comment: @unxnut, doesn't `${!$}` expand to value of variable having name equal to shell's PID?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As it says it is an indirect reference.  Take the following example:

```
$ var=test
$ test='Hello, world'
$ echo ${!var}
Hello, world
```

Now if I were to set the following positional parameters:

```
$ set -- one two three
```

And `$#` will represent the total number of positional parameters:

```
$ echo $#
3
```

This means when I call it like `${!#}` I'm saying give me the value of the parameter named `3`:

```
$ echo ${!#}
three
```